# HOG in Matlab - split images into blocks and calculate the orientations

Tags: matlab, image-processing, orientation, block, histogram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdb9P.png)I have a problem. I have implemented the code to split image into blocks 
calculating the orientations for each block, this is the code:

```html
a=imread('009055_0M54.JPG'); a1=imresize(a,[300,340]); 
cbs=100; 
ck1=1; cblock(:,:,:,1)=a1(1:100,1:100,:); 
cblock(:,:,:,5)=a1(101:200,1:100,:); 
cblock(:,:,:,9)=a1(201:300,1:100,:); 
for ci1=1:3 
ck1=ck1+1; 
for cj1=1:3 
row1=80 ; 
row2=180; 
cblock(:,:,:,ck1)=a1( (cbs*(ci1-1)+1:cbs*(ci1-1)+cbs), ((row1+1)+(cj1-1)*80:row2+(cj1-1)*80),:); 

ck1=ck1+1; 
[featureVector, hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(cblock(:,:,:,ck1));
figure;
imshow(cblock(:,:,:,ck1)); hold on;
plot(hogVisualization);
   

end 

end
```

It works, but some blocks are black, without image. If for example I edit this line:

```html
imshow(cblock(:,:,:,1)); hold on;
```

the program shows to me 6 equal block, it works well! But for example, I edit that line in:

```html
imshow(cblock(:,:,:,3)); hold on;
```

The program shows to me 6 blocks, of which 5 equal blocks and the first block such as a black block, without image! In fact when i used the main code:

```html
imshow(cblock(:,:,:,ck1)); hold on;
```

the block 3 is a black code! Please, help me!
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

To try replicate one would need where the image comes from and also extractHOGFeatures function ?

Comment: What? I do not know what you mean

Comment: Give us a link to the image you are using and where are those matlab scripts of the ExtractHOGFeatures function, so we try to help you by replicating what you do

Comment: this is my image http://imgur.com/gallery/RjNHXKk 
I use the code in this page http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/28166-magnitude-and-direction
with this:http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop&requestedDomain=it.mathworks.com